# AndEngine : Music volume won't adjust correctly

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using following code in `onSceneTouchEvent` :

```
if(audioControlButton.contains(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY())
         && pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    toggleVolume();
}
```

And everything is works fine, method is invoking when it has to. `toggleVolume()` has this implementation :

```
if(levelMusic.getVolume() != 0f) {
    levelMusic.setVolume(0f);
} else { 
    levelMusic.setVolume(100f);
}
```

All of the condition seems to work, but the issue comes here: 
**If levelMusic.setVolume(0f) is ivoked music volume disables as it should be, but if levelMusic.setVolume(100f) invokes still i can't hear the music**

**Note** : I've also tried `pause()` and `resume()` and it's not working as well

My levelMusic variable:

```
Music levelMusic; //field in scene class
levelMusic = data.getLevelMusic();
levelMusic.play();
```

In onResourcesLoadingFinished

**EDIT** : i've also tried to set value to 60 instead of 100 and to 0,9f(if max malue is 1f), but it's not working too

Comment: Are you trying to implement mute/Unmute music for your option screen?

Answer (score 0):

If someone will have this problem :

Use 
`levelMusic.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f); // 0f wont work`

so, whole method should be looking like this:

```
if(levelMusic.getVolume() != 0.0f) {
    levelMusic.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
} else { 
    levelMusic.setVolume(1f);
}
```